# Ignore missing .obj files or "/P switch + external tool + linker = hell"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor

I am trying to make a setup as described in my previous question: [Any way to parse preprocessed source through external tool before it compiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099415/any-way-to-parse-preprocessed-source-through-external-tool-before-it-compiles)

All of my .cpp files are set to compile with /p, which generates .i (preprocessed) files for all of them, but no object files. Those generated .i files are also added to my project, and an external build tool option is set to my tool that modifies those files, and saves them under new extension, .obfuscated.cpp
All those .obfuscated.cpp files are also added to the project, and are set to compile normally, producing object files.

Now the problem is that Visual Studio (or the linker, someone of them) for some reason want the obj files both from .cpp files (which now are just saved to .i files, no object files produced), and from .obfuscated.cpp (which are created normally).

I would assume that the linker would not require .obj files from sources that are set to compile with /P option, because, well that option prevents object files from being created.

Now I only see two ways to solve this:
1) Do the build in two steps. In the first one make sure all the .cpp files are preprocessed and saved to .i files. This build does not have to complete, just has to save .i files. Then after that, I select all the .cpp files and set them to "Exclude from build", then everything compiles as it should.
2) Instead of adding the files to the project and using the external build tool option, make a pre-link step instead, in which my own tool would automatically find all the .i files (could take all *.i in a certain directory), process them to *.obfuscated.cpp, and then manually call cl.exe on all of those files to produce object files, rename them to proper names (so that the linker thinks they are object files created from original sources) and put into intermediate directory. But in this case I would have to keep track of all the compiler arguments and change them accordingly if something changes in my project...
Both of these solutions don't seem very beatuful. Is there some other way to do this in Visual Studio? Can't I just tell the linker to ignore missing .obj files? (All the symbols will be found anyway...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help you : instead of the extension `.obfuscated.cpp` give it an simpler extension like `.icpp` and add those `.icpp` files (after first compile) to your project (in a separate folder in your project) ,then for each of those `.icpp` files goto their property-page and set the correct build-tool (C\C++ compiler) and your `.obj` files retain the same name-part as your original `.cpp` files so linking should automatically be done correctly.

Comment: Nope, now it doesn't even want to compile the .icpp (I even tried naming them .cpp, i.e. same name as the original, but in different directory), and does not produce any object files for it... Also, if I even just right click a .icpp file and click Compile, it compiles the original again (to produce an .i file), seems almost like a bug in VS... Your solution really sounded like the last possible thing that could work, but I guess there is no easy way to do this without a proper build system...

Comment: @Cray: too bad ,hope you'll find a solution.

Comment: @Cray: you could try to set the compile options regarding preprocessing to a file for the .icpp file to not processing to a file.

Comment: Yep, that I did of course, still the same result. I have kind of given up now, just wrote a good description of how to do this thing in the future. It's not as good as if it was really simple, but still works. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I just wanted to *see* the result of the preprocessing (no extra external tool or so).
I ended with the following solution:

- I create an empty object file: just add an empty source "dummy.cpp" to your     project.
  NOTE: dummy.cpp must be empty, otherwise the Linker will complain about
  duplicate symbols.
- I mark the "*.icpp" sources as "C++-Compiler" and /P
  as mentioned above.
- I create a PreLink action, containing a
  `copy $(IntDir)dummy.obj $(IntDir)xyz.obj`
  for each "xyz.icpp" source.
- if you want **both compiled and precompiled** output:
  add a *`xyz-wrapper.cpp`* for each *`xyz.icpp`*.
  The wrapper should contain only one line like this:
  `#include "xyz.icpp"`

Now the Linker still searches for the  xyz-objects, which are still not created, but we give it the empty dummy objects.

NOTE: to get Syntax-Highlighting for the `*.icpp` files in VisualStudio, you should add this extension at ->Tools->Options->TextEditor->FileExtensions